Prisma Error: P1017: Server has closed the connection
I'm following a course, here is the link
halfway through the course he started testing the code but made another database connection and created a new .env name it .env.test
in .env
PORT=3002
JWT_SECRET=secret
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=MySQL.Bebon3232
DB_HOST=db_test
DB_NAME=learning_nestjs
DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:MySQL.Bebon3232@localhost:3307/learning_nestjs"

in .env.test
PORT=3002
JWT_SECRET=secret
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=MySQL.Bebon3232
DB_HOST=db_test
DB_NAME=learning_nestjs
DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:MySQL.Bebon3232@localhost:3308/learning_nestjs"

the only difference is the port number
while in docker-compose
version: '3.8'

services:
  dev_db:
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3307:3306
    expose:
      - 3307
    volumes:
      - ./db_data:/data/db
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_USER=${DB_USERNAME}
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${DB_NAME}

  test_db:
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3308:3306
    expose:
      - 3308
    volumes:
      - ./db_data:/data/db
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_USER=${DB_USERNAME}
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${DB_NAME}

when running the code everything works just fine, untell the testing part.
this is the scripts for running the code
"prisma:dev:deploy": "prisma migrate deploy",
"db:dev:up": "docker compose up dev_db -d",
"db:dev:rm": "docker compose rm dev_db -s -f -v",
"db:dev:restart": "yarn db:dev:rm && yarn db:dev:up && yarn prisma:dev:deploy",

"prisma:test:deploy": "dotenv -e .env.test -- prisma migrate deploy",
"db:test:up": "docker compose up test_db -d",
"db:test:rm": "docker compose rm test_db -s -f -v",
"db:test:restart": "yarn db:test:rm && yarn db:test:up && yarn prisma:test:deploy",

"build": "nest build",
"start": "nest start",
"start:dev": "nest start --watch",

"pretest:e2e": "yarn db:test:restart",
"test:e2e": "dotenv -e .env.test -- jest --watchAll --no-cache --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"

I run test:e2e which runs the following commands by order before it runs itself

yarn compose rm test_db -s -f -v
yarn compose up test_db -d
dotenv -e .env.test -- prisma migrate deploy

and it stops when Prisma deploys and shows this error
Error: P1017: Server has closed the connection.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

Even though running the commands separately
npx dotenv -e .env.test -- prisma migrate deploy

npx dotenv -e .env.test -- jest --watchAll --no-cache --config ./test/jest-e2e.json

work just fine alone but not as a group of commands
it should pass the test that has been made, which is
import { INestApplication, ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Test } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { AppModule } from '../src/app.module';

describe('app e2e', () => {
  let app: INestApplication;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    const moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [AppModule],
    }).compile();

    app = moduleRef.createNestApplication();
    app.useGlobalPipes(
      new ValidationPipe({
        whitelist: true,
      }),
    );
    await app.init();
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await app.close();
  });

  it.todo('should pass');
});


Note that the database containers (dev_db & test_db) work completely

The volumes: blocks on both databases are wrong.  On the one hand, they mount data into the wrong directory, so the container doesn't see the persistent storage (you will get an automatically-created anonymous volume).  On the other, they both try to mount the same host directory, which in principle should give them the same data (and cause errors if both containers try to start at the same time).  Is the database container actually running?

yes the database containers (dev_db & test_db) are running just fine
